# dialogflow nodejs client showing no security token sent error

Tags: node.js, heroku, jwt, botframework, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate my Dialogflow agent with Skype. I follow this link https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples/skype to customize my bot responses. The webhook is deployed on Heroku. The issue is that I am getting this error "error: chatconnector: receive - no security token sent" always. The below CURL request looks fine

```
curl -X POST \
  https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'postman-token: 2774cb69-14bb-7247-d3bb-7bdda2de0e4c' \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=f6f66a29-f184-48a0-9913-bda96c22be4f&client_secret=bkVCGV20*%25%2BfoicfITP333%40&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default'
```

You can test this code and it clearly says there is no issue with Microsoft API regarding authentication. I am really stuck with this. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Where is the error coming from?  You're calling a `microsoftonline.com` URL, how does this related to Dialogflow?

Comment: I am trying to integrate a chatbot created in dialogflow with skype. for this, if you want to check whether your microsoft appid and password combination is wrong the above curl request can be used. the request itself returs result and it is working fine.the error mentioned is regarding jwt token. if you see the curn request response, you can see it is coming.

Comment: Could you make sure that the environment variables `process.env.APP_ID` and `process.env.APP_SECRET` are set right on heroku and successfull passed into your runtime?

Comment: @matthewayne: I have given it directly by hardcoding. still no success

Comment: And you are including the app.ai client access token as well, correct?  (which would be referenced in the sample's app.json)